# how to reduce the getConnection time consume in Atomikos

Tags: spring-data-jpa, jta, xa, atomikos

I am using Atomkios XA configuration for Oracle.

This is my code for creating datasource connection.

```
    OracleXADataSource oracleXADataSource = new OracleXADataSource();
    oracleXADataSource.setURL(sourceURL);
    oracleXADataSource.setUser(UN);
    oracleXADataSource.setPassword(PS);

    AtomikosDataSourceBean sourceBean= new AtomikosDataSourceBean();
    sourceBean.setXaDataSource(oracleXADataSource);
    sourceBean.setUniqueResourceName(resourceName);
    sourceBean.setMaxPoolSize(max-pool-size);   // 10 


atomikos:
      datasource:
        resourceName: insight
        max-pool-size: 10
        min-pool-size: 3
    transaction-manager-id: insight-services-tm
```

This is my configuration is fine for medium user load around 5000 requests.

But when user count increases assume more than 10000 requests, this class com.atomikos.jdbc.AbstractDataSourceBean:getConnection consuming more then than normal.

This class time taking approximately 1500ms but normal time it takes less then 10ms. I can understand user demand increases, getConnection is going to wait state to pick the free connection from the connection pool so if I increase my max-pool-size, will my problem sort out or any other option feature available to sort out my problem.

Answer (score 0):

Try setting concurrentConnectionValidation=true on your datasource.

If that does not help then consider a free trial of the commercial Atomikos product:

https://www.atomikos.com/Main/ExtremeTransactionsFreeTrial

Best